# Update panel trigger error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I am filtering the gridview on the selection of the values from the dropdown list. The problem is that when I select any value it gives me the correct result, but when I select the default value means `Select the value` the gridview still gives me error as `No Records Found`.

I tried implementing update panel for that, so that it can be handled through it. But I am facing the error as below:

**Could not find an event named 'Click' on associated control 'grdCSRPageData' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'updgridPage'.**

Please see my code as I for the update panel:-

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updgridPage" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="grdCSRPageData" runat="server" Width="100%" border="1" Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;" CellPadding="3"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBound="grdCSRPageData_DataBound" AllowPaging="true" CssClass="hoverTable" EmptyDataText="No Records Found"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="grdCSRPageData_PageIndexChanging" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDeleting="grdCSRPageData_RowDeleting"
                    PageSize="5" ShowFooter="true" OnRowEditing="grdCSRPageData_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="grdCSRPageData_RowUpdating"
                    OnRowCancelingEdit="grdCSRPageData_RowCancelingEdit">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="k-alt" BackColor="#f5f5f5" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="page_title" HeaderText="Page Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="page_description" HeaderText="Page Description" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_title" HeaderText="Meta Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_keywords" HeaderText="Meta Keywords" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_description" HeaderText="Meta Description" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ItemStyle-Width="15" EditImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-Width="15" ControlStyle-Height="15" CancelImageUrl="~/images/close.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/images/update.png">
                            <ControlStyle Height="20px" Width="20px"></ControlStyle>
                        </asp:CommandField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="grdCSRPageData" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Do let me know what changes I have to make.

Filter code for the gridview:-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPagesNgo" runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker form-control-drp wd" Style="width: 100%" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPagesNgo_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

SelectedIndexChangedCode:-

```
 protected void ddlPagesNgo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGridView(ddlPagesNgo.SelectedValue);
    }
```

BindGridView Code:-

```
public void BindGridView(string NgoId)
    {
        string strQuery = "select Id,page_title,page_description,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,Active from tbl_Pages WHERE NgoId=" + NgoId + " ORDER By Id DESC";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        grdCSRPageData.DataSource = dt;
        grdCSRPageData.DataBind(); 
    }
```

Do let me know if you need anything else

Comment: A `GridView` dos not have a click event as the error says. What event do you want to hook the trigger to?

Comment: I want when dropdown list is on the default selection. The default gridview value should come. currently it shows me "No records found"

Comment: @BenRobinson:I want when dropdown list is on the default selection. The default gridview value should come. currently it shows me "No records found" Any help on these

Comment: It sounds like your problem is the code that filters the gridview, you should have it return all records if the "default" selection is picked.

Comment: @BenRobinson: Exactly you got the point, do you want to have a look at my filter code ?

Comment: Yes I may be able to help if you posted your filter code.

Comment: @BenRobinson: See the updated question, do let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66659/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-ben-robinson).

Comment: @BenRobinson: any updates pls, i am waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

use this code. Your mistake is click EventName is wrong

```
<Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="grdCSRPageData" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: i applied but when I select the default selection from the dropdown, I still get the `No records found`. can you help me with that

Answer (score 0):

Got it done by putting if else condition

```
 public void BindGridView(string NgoId)
    {
        string strQuery = null;

        if (NgoId != "0")
            strQuery = "select Id,page_title,page_description,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,Active from tbl_Pages WHERE NgoId=" + NgoId + " ORDER By Id DESC";
        else
            strQuery = "select Id,page_title,page_description,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,Active from tbl_Pages ORDER By Id DESC";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        grdCSRPageData.DataSource = dt;
        grdCSRPageData.DataBind(); 
    }
```